# How to easily build wireshark dissector plugin as dll?

Tags: gcc, dll, mingw, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I modified an unclompete Wireshark dissector plugin, i.e. I did some modifications to the already existing c-files. I neither added a new file in the plugin directory nor did I add some new includes in the c-files. I just added some missing functionality in the c-files. Now I want to build a dll file out of the source files. Is there a way to do this without installing the whole toolchain (Visual Studion, Qt, Cygwin, Python, ...) and building the whole Wireshark as described here https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSetupWin32.html? I just want to compile the few c-files with gcc (MinGW), put them into a dll and replace the old dll with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked and answered on [ask.wireshark.org question 43824](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/43824/how-to-easily-build-wireshark-dissector-plugin-as-dll).